# UITableView InfiniteScrolling without reloading TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to implement Infinite Scrolling using paginated API in UITableView. So I am updating Model(calling API again and appending results) as bottom cell is reached and reloading whole UITableView. Problem I am facing is, I see flicker on screen when that reloading is done but I just want to add more cells in tableView in smooth manner without any flicker. Here is What I have wrote for same:

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    private var feed: Feed!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        feed = Feed(delegate: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        feed.fetch(nextPage: true)
    }
}

//MARK: TableView
extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feed.articles.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row < feed.articles.count {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedTableViewCell") as? FeedTableViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setCell(article: feed.articles[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        else if feed.articles.count > 0 && !feed.hasReachedEnd {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoaderTableViewCell") as? LoaderTableViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            cell.addLoader()
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == feed.articles.count && !feed.hasReachedEnd {
            feed.fetch(nextPage: true)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: API Management
extension FeedViewController: FeedProtocol {
    func requestCompletedSuccessfully() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.loader.stopAnimating()
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func requestFailedWith(error: NSError?) {}
}
```

Here you may see that, as soon as fetch request is complete, using delegation I am reloading whole tableView there, But I need some better solution if possible to avoid that flickering.
Please Let me know if something else is required. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is calling `tableView.reloadRows` not `tableView.reloadData`. But in order to do that you need to know how many new elements you have in your feed when requestCompletedSuccessfully executes. Something like:

```
let indexPaths = Array(previousFeedCount..<newFeedCount)
    .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, But this is giving me following error.. 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 19 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update' while api request successful while opening app..

Comment: Hi Kautsya, I'm familiar with that error but I'd have to see what you are doing in your code.

Comment: You may find whole code here.. https://github.com/kautsiitd/NewsApp I just want to know better solution than reloading tableView while adding more data on feed on successful Api call.. Please let me know if I something more is required..

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing. Since you are using core data you should be using an NSFetchResultsController. You can automatically detect when new articles are added to core data. When that happens, you will simply update your table view with the new data. Here are a couple excellent articles to get you going. https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3 and https://cocoacasts.com/implement-the-nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-protocol-with-swift-3

Comment: Yes, but I am using CoreData only for first time while open the app, If someone clicks on refresh then I use paginated API to fetch Headlines in chunk of 20. How to handle infinite scrolling in remote case then? You may see updated project again. And in FeedViewController you would notice that I am just reloading whole tableView on successful api at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use scrollView Delegate, tableview is byDefault inherited from UIScrollView and set delegate to self.

```
extension FeedViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
       func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if self.tableView.contentOffset.y <= -10  {

            // table view reached top place your pull to refresh call here
        } else if ((tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.frame.size.height) >= tableView.contentSize.height) {
            //table view reached last record, fetch next records here
            // tableview usually flickers if content to be reloaded is out of screen bounds. There is one hack to avoid that, add replace these three lines with tableView.reloadData() line
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            tableView.reloadData()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: that would be very bad hack but.. any other solution I would prefer @umer